# How to know if API Version upgrade will effect AKS function or not?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I recently got an email saying I need to upgrade my AKS API Version 2023-03-01-preview as it is about to be deprecated. I was wondering how will I know if this upgrade/deprecation will affect functions applied to my AKS and prevent me from using certain functions in the future. I recently applied Helm chart AGIC to my AKS and it is essential to me that this function remains and can be applied to future clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading your AKS API version, it's important to check for any deprecated APIs that could affect your application or development process.
Microsoft uses Azure Advisor under your Kubernetes services to alert you inside the Azure portal if you're out of support and inform you of deprecated APIs that can affect your application or development process.
[image]

plus, you can also setup diagnostics specifically for k8s API to track these details.

[image]

Additionally, as per [Stop Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster upgrades automatically on API breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/stop-cluster-upgrade-api-breaking-changes#stop-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-cluster-upgrades-automatically-on-api-breaking-changes) AKS now automatically stops upgrade operations consisting of a minor version change with deprecated APIs and sends you an error message to alert you about the issue exactly how you got. Now I would recommend that you carefully read the deprecation notice from Azure. It usually contains information about what's changing and may provide links to documentation detailing the differences between API versions. This documentation often includes a section on breaking changes or migration guides that detail the differences and what you need to consider when upgrading.
[image]

To ensure that your essential functions, such as specific concerns about Helm charts for AGIC, you should check the Helm chart’s [documentation](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/ingress-v1/#:%7E:text=Note:%20Ingress/V1%20is%20fully%20supported%20with%20AGIC,the%20API%20server%20translates%20any%20Ingress%20v1beta1) or [repository](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress) for any compatibility notes regarding Kubernetes versions and any necessary updates to the Helm chart itself. Look for a section usually labeled as "Release Notes," "Changelog"

And finally, I would recommend, before upgrading your production cluster, create a test cluster with the new AKS API version and deploy your workloads, including the Application Gateway Ingress Controller (AGIC) and other critical services, to verify that everything functions as expected.

References:

- [Stop Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster upgrades automatically on API breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/stop-cluster-upgrade-api-breaking-changes#stop-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-cluster-upgrades-automatically-on-api-breaking-changes)
- [Supported Kubernetes versions in Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions#faq)